# how to get an empty Json object with Zend_json?

Tags: json, zend-framework

From http://json.org/:

> an empty Json object is:
>
> ```
> {}
> ```

I've tried to get it with `json_encode` (which is officially part of PHP):

```
json_encode((object)(array()))
```

that's what I need. But somehow I have to use `Zend_json` to get it:

```
Zend_Json::encode((object)(array()))
```

but the result is:

```
{"__className": "stdClass"}
```

Any ideas?

*My PHP version 5.1.6; ZF version 1.7.2*

Answer (score 2):

For me this works perfectly:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r(Zend_Json::encode((object)array())); echo '</pre>'; exit;
// Output: {}
```

Tested with ZF-Version 1.11.3

Also possible:

```
Zend_Json::encode(new stdClass());
```

Comment: thx, both of them output {"__className": "stdClass"}
My ZF-version 1.7. 
I will ask if my team leader would like to get a new ZF.

Comment: It's strange. I have read the code of ZendFramework-1.11.5-minimal/library/Zend/Json/Encoder.php, and get the following:

Encode an object to JSON by encoding each of the public properties. A special property is added to the JSON object called '__className' that contains the name of the class of $value. This is used to decode the object on the client into a specific class.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Zend_Json::encode(array());
```

Comment: it return a Json array [], not {}

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anybody is still wondering, the internal encoder of the ZF adds the __className property to each object. 
The internal encoder is used if the PECL extension json is not installed and thus the function json_encode not available (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php ).

Just use

```
preg_replace('/"__className":"[^"]+",/', '', $jsonString);
```

to get rid of all className elements

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution as below:

```
$m = Zend_Json::encode($obj);
$res = str_replace('"__className":"stdClass"', '', $m);
$res = str_replace("'__className':'stdClass'", '', $res);
$res = str_replace("'__className': 'stdClass'", '', $res);
$res = str_replace('"__className": "stdClass"', '', $res);
return $res;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get around this in Zf2 I have added a `disableClassNameDecoding` option to `Zend\Json\Encoder`.

If you want to disable the `__className` output, you can use it like this:

```
return Zend\Json\Json::encode($object, false, array('disableClassNameDecoding' => true));
```

The patched file can be found on [github](https://github.com/djskinner/zf2/blob/5a67379b3db48fe495059c37bcaf001c2f0070fe/library/Zend/Json/Encoder.php). At some point I will add unit tests and create a pull request.